# local variable 'random' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, python-3.x

local variable 'random' referenced before assignment

```
import random
from random import randrange
from random import randint

def function(request):
    random = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    print("random :",random)
    return HttpResponse(random)
```

Comment: Pick another name for your variable, `random` is already used by the random module.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling random correctly here.You have a redundant import: once via `import random` and via `from random import randint`. This is further complicated by trying to use a local variable with the name random, which is the same name as the module you imported.

You can either import using `import random`, which imports all functions/classes from random module. Or you can be more specific in your imports by using the `from random import randint`.

Method 1:

```py
import random
# Use
random.randint(1000,1999)
```

Method 2:

```py
from random import randint
# use
randint(1000,1999)
```